# C++ newbie: template function problem--getting string and numerical data from text file, putting it in vector

Tags: c++, templates, stream

I am a newbie.  I have tried to write a template function that gets string AND numerical data (for example, douubles) from a text file, then puts it in a vector.  Each element of the vector is a different name or number.

Last week I asked whether overloading or a template might be best for this.  I would like to go with a template method, where the results vector (what I want) is passed to the function to provide the template parameter T.  But I'm having problems.  If anyone could help, I would be grateful!  The code is below, followed by the error I'm getting.

// My code:

```
template<typename T>
void readFile( const std::string& name, const std::string& find, std::vector<T>& results ){
    std::ifstream file( name.c_str( ) );
    std::string   line;

    while( std::getline( file, line ) )
    {
        if( line == find )
        {
            std::getline( file, line );
            line.erase(remove( line.begin(), line.end(), '\'' ), line.end() );
            std::istringstream streamLine( line );

            results = std::vector<T>( std::istream_iterator<T>(streamLine), std::istream_iterator<T>() );
        }
    }
}
```

Call in main():

```
readFile( name, "label", results );
```

The error I'm getting is below.  I don't understand how the function call doesn't match the definition.  Apologies in advance for any dumb mistakes!

```
error: no matching function for call to 
'std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >,
std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >
::resize(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)'
```

The weird thing is that if I make the function return the vector "result" instead of void, then things seem to work.  Here's what I mean:

```
std::vector<T> readFile( const std::string& name, const std::string& find, std::vector<T>& results )
```

with a return statement in the function definition of:

```
return std::vector<T>( std::istream_iterator<T>(streamLine), std::istream_iterator<T>() );
```

But it seems clunky/bad style to do it this way.  I would have thought that using references would be better.  Even if it isn't better, I'm curious to know why the first method (with void) doesn't work.

Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: what does `results` and the code before the call the `readFile` look like?

Comment: Hi Nim...                                                            In main():                                                      const std::string name = "test.dat";                                                       Then std::vector<std::string> results;

Comment: returning the vector may not be bad. If you assign it straight into a local variable the compiler may be able to elide away the copy. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization .

Comment: Hi tenpn.  So you're saying that it is OK to define the function as:              std::vector<T> readFile( const std::string& name, const std::string& find, std::vector<T>& results )                                                                And then in main() do results = readFile( name, "label", results );

Comment: @Ant: Though being unrelated probably,
the error itself indicates that something like
`results.resize( name )` or `results.resize( find )` exists in your code.

Comment: @Ant, is there anywhere in your code where you call `resize` on the vector? because it looks like there is a line somewhere where `resize` is being called, but the argument is wrong (should be integral, but a string is being passed...)

Comment: The code you've posted appears to have no problems. Personally though, I'd have it return a `::std::vector<T>` and not take an argument. Then it will have to called like this: `read_file< ::std::string>("name", "find");`. I think that's clearer anyway. The only problem is that it's not very efficient until C++0x and move assignment is here.

Comment: Hi Nim, Omnifarious, and Ise.  Hmm....  I don't call resize at all, anywhere. I thought the stl vector class would take care of that.  Omnifarious, I did hear that using return to return the results would be less efficient than using references (returning void and using reference parameter), but I could get the references method to work (error that function args don't match call).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do a bunch of work to make this a fully compilable code snippet. Here is what I came up with:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <istream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T>
void readFile(const std::string& name,
              const std::string& find,
              std::vector<T>& results )
{
   std::ifstream file( name.c_str( ) );
   std::string   line;

   while( std::getline( file, line ) )
   {
      if( line == find )
      {
         std::getline( file, line );
         line.erase(remove( line.begin(), line.end(), '\'' ), line.end() );
         std::istringstream streamLine( line );

         results = std::vector<T>( std::istream_iterator<T>(streamLine),
                                   std::istream_iterator<T>() );
      }
   }
}

void do_it_with_strings(std::vector<std::string> &results)
{
   readFile("fred", "barney", results);
}
```

This code snippet compiles just fine with gcc 4.5.1. What are the exact types of `name` and `results` in your `main` function? Also, the problem seems to be calling the vector's `resize` function. You don't appear to be doing that directly in your code, though it's possible the vector constructor or assignment operator does it internally.

But regardless, I wouldn't suggest you write your code that way anyway. I would suggest you do this instead:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <istream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T>
std::vector<T> readFile(const std::string& name, const std::string& find )
{
   std::ifstream file( name.c_str( ) );
   std::string   line;

   while( std::getline( file, line ) )
   {
      if( line == find )
      {
         std::getline( file, line );
         line.erase(remove( line.begin(), line.end(), '\'' ), line.end() );
         std::istringstream streamLine( line );

         return std::vector<T>( std::istream_iterator<T>(streamLine),
                                std::istream_iterator<T>() );
      }
   }
   return std::vector<T>();
}

void do_it_with_strings(std::vector<std::string> &results)
{
   results = readFile<std::string>("fred", "barney");
}
```

In a function like this, I think it's better to be explicitly stating the type you're expecting to read when you call the function rather than have it implicitly determined from the type of the `vector` you pass in.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Omnifarious.  If you have time, it would be great if you could explain why you defined "remove."  I thought that was something provided by STL (I haven't defined it).  Also, I don't really understand what "move assignment" in STL in C++0x will be, but I guess the efficiency cost of using return will not be that inconvenient for me, so I'll use return.  Thanks a lot for taking so much time to help!!

Comment: @Ant - It's because I forgot that std::remove existed, and since you had left `remove` unqualified but had qualified `getline` I thought it was a function you had defined.

Comment: @Ant - There, I fixed my question to use the STL `remove`.

Comment: Thanks Omnifarious.  I tried your example and it does compile, but I find that I need to include the results vector (std::vector<T>& result) as a parameter in the definition to get it to run.  Otherwise it throws an exception that I added in.  It's so weird.  I just don't understand why it works that way.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a piece of code which will get you either strings or numerical values from a file:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T>
void read_values(const std::string& filename, std::vector<T>& coll)
{
    std::fstream file(filename);

    std::copy (std::istream_iterator<T>(file),    
               std::istream_iterator<T>(),
               back_inserter(coll));

    std::sort(coll.begin(), coll.end());

    coll.erase(std::unique(coll.begin(), coll.end()), coll.end());
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> values;
    read_values("C:\\example.txt", values);

    return 0;
}
```

If you wish to read string values instead, you just need to provide a std::vector of std::string to pass into the template function.